# MySQL 5.7 on W2K12 essentials - starts fine and then fails after restart

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I have a W2K12 Essentials server that I'm trying to get MySQL 5.7 running on for in house development.  It installs just fine - I change install and data directories to two separate directories on the D:\ drive.

Service starts as normal.  I stop it, go in and change the Logon to Local System Account with Allow Service to Interact with Desktop (installer sets it to Network Service).  Restart service just fine.

Open up my.cnf to change the innodb_buffer_pool_size to 1G. Save changes.  Won't start (Services hangs on Starting).  Revert change back to 8M.  Service still won't start and eventually fails.

Event viewer shows "The MySQL57 service terminated unexpectedly.  It has done this 2 time(s)."

Task manager shows mysqld running but using only about 1.2mb of memory.

UPDATE - just uninstalled and reinstalled again.  Left the Log on as Network Service, but gave Network Service full permissions on my MySQL folder and my MySQLData folder.

Stopped and restarted numerous times.

Copy my.cnf to a safe place.  Change innodb_buffer_pool_size from 8M to 48M.  Won't start (again Task Manager shows 1.3mb memory usage).  Kill task.  Switch it back to 8M.  Still won't start.  Overwrite my.cnf with my backup copy and now it works again.  I am changing nothing else in that file and using notepad.exe to edit it.

Comment: Is there an error log (hostname.err in datadir) that has a hint?

Comment: How much RAM in the machine?  Did you change anything else in my.cnf?

Comment: Consider posting your complete error log to consider possible causes.

Comment: It appears that it might have been notepad.exe.  when I switched to. Notepad++ I was able to edit the ini file and server restarted.

Comment: We are glad you are running again.  View my profile, Network profile for contact info.